# How to add to swagger both json and form data to request body using swagger-lume?

Tags: json, forms, swagger

I am trying to put json and form data in swagger request body but i dont know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using swagger-lume, can anybody help me where to put components key?

Comment: Do you mean 1) [JSON as part of a `multipart` request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44323585/113116), or 2) a request that accepts [_either_ JSON _or_ form data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42287298/113116)?

Comment: 2, request that accepts either form data or json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write swagger doc that consumes multiple content types e.g. application/json AND application/x-www-form-urlencoded (w/o duplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287298/write-swagger-doc-that-consumes-multiple-content-types-e-g-application-json-and)

Comment: Thanks Helen, this partially solves my problem. But do you by any chance know where to put components key in swagger-lume annotations?